# CMake find packages using find_package in submodules folder

Tags: cmake

```
Root
  CMakeLists.txt
  Valyrie/
    CMakeLists.txt
  Submodules/
    CMakeLists.txt
    SubmodulePackage/
       CMakeLists.txt
```

I have a directory structure listed like above. However even if I `add_subdirectory("submodules")` so the submodule packages get added first cmake won't find the packages with `find_package` inside the Valkyrie cmakelists.txt. Is there a way to do that? I'd do relative path, but some submodules don't seem to get brought in correctly by just relative pathing their header files for some reason (header-only library).

Root Level Cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project (Valkyrie)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory("submodules")
add_subdirectory("Valkyrie")
```

Submodules CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory("json")
add_subdirectory("spdlog")
add_subdirectory("glfw")
add_subdirectory("entt")
add_subdirectory("glm")
```

Valkyrie

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED) #Error here

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.h")

add_library(Valkyrie ${headers} ${sources})
target_compile_features(Valkyrie PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

target_include_directories(Valkyrie
    PUBLIC "../submodules/glfw/include"
    PUBLIC "../submodules/glm"
    PUBLIC "../submodules/entt/single_include"
    PUBLIC "../submodules/spdlog/include"
    PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(Valkyrie
"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/submodules/glfw/src/glfw3.lib"
${Vulkan_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: "Standard" scripts for `find_package` expect corresponding package to be **already installed**. So `find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)` expects spdlog to be **already installed**, not just *configured* (via `add_subdirectory(spdlog)`). If you use `Findspdlog.cmake` script, then you could try to tell the script, that **searching** is not needed because include directory is already known. Usually this could be performed via setting CACHE variable noted in the error message.